# Looking for a Smart Banner plugin for Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I was looking for a Smart Banner plugin that can detect the OS of mobile users, if Android or iPhone, then show a banner advertising that we have an app for their mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Native app install banners from Google:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/app-install-banners/

> They let users quickly and seamlessly add your web or native app to
>   their home screens without leaving the browser.

There is a small GIF in the site where you can see that the users can install your app even without leaving the browser.

Comment: Will this link users to the app on the Google Play store?

Comment: Yes. There is a GIF at the bottom of that page. You can see how the install process works in that GIF. And the install process is so easy to the users.

Answer (score 1):

Up to now, the easiest solution I've found is to use:

- [native Smart banner for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)
- [AppBanners wordpress plugin for Android](https://wordpress.org/plugins/appbanners/)

Just leave blank **Apple App ID** field, this way WordPress will show native banner for iOS and AppBanners banner for Android.

Native iOS banner installation on WordPress is very easy. Just insert metatag line into a header of header.php file:

[image]